# Neo4j - Cypher | Timestamp when a relationship takes place

Tags: neo4j, timestamp, cypher

I have a Spring boot app where i have defined some Queries.
In of them i would like the database to track a timestamp at the time a certain query is fired and store it in a property of a node.
There is a function timestamp() but i cant find in the docs what kind of args this takes and how to use it properly.

Lets say i have this query:

```
MATCH (p:Patient) WHERE ID(p) = ({0})
MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE ID(d) IN ({1})
CREATE (p)-[:GETS]->(d)
```

Lets say the user inserts the parameters, i would like to have a timestamp at every (d) node.

Tried this:

```
MATCH (p:Patient) WHERE ID(p) = 1693
MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE ID(d) IN [1671, 1679]
CREATE (p)-[:GETS]->(d {givenDate: datetime()})
```

But I get the error:

> Cant create node 'd' with labels or properties here. The variable is
>   already declared.

Seems like i am doing something wrong but i would like that both 1671 + 1679 get a new property givenDate with a datetime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [timestamp](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-timestamp) function is documented to return:

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and
>   midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. It is the equivalent of
>   [datetime().epochMillis](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/functions/temporal/datetime/#functions-datetime-timestamp).

2. Your `CREATE` clause is trying to create a new node with the variable name `d`, which is not allowed since `d` is already declared (by the prior `MATCH` clause) for a different node. I suspect, though, you do not want to create a new node, but add a timestamp to the existing `d` node instead.

   This should work (and gurantee that all the `Drug` nodes are created with the same `datetime` value):

   ```
   WITH datetime() AS dt
   MATCH (p:Patient) WHERE ID(p) = 1693
   MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE ID(d) IN [1671, 1679]
   SET d.givenDate = dt
   CREATE (p)-[:GETS]->(d)
   ```

   **However**, there is a big flaw in your overall approach. Since there is only a single `Drug` node with a given native ID, every time a different patient takes the same drug, the existing `givenDate` will be changed. It would make more sense to put the `datetime` in the `GETS` relationship:

   ```
   WITH datetime() AS dt
   MATCH (p:Patient) WHERE ID(p) = 1693
   MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE ID(d) IN [1671, 1679]
   CREATE (p)-[:GETS {givenDate: dt}]->(d)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked.
About your notice, i already took care about it.
Every node that has a :GETS relationship does not appear in my search function any more, so this scenario is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

try this (also assuming that it might be better to put the timestamp on the relationship)

```
MATCH (p:Patient) WHERE ID(p) = 1693 
MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE ID(d) IN [1671, 1679] 
CREATE (p)-[r:GETS]->(d)
SET r.givenDate= datetime()
```

if you think the timestamp should be on d

```
SET d.givenDate= datetime()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the SET clause of cypher to add new or update existing properties of a node

```
MATCH (p:Patient) 
WHERE ID(p) = 1693 
MATCH (d:Drug) 
WHERE ID(d) IN [1671, 1679] 
SET d.givenDate = datetime()
CREATE (p)-[:GETS]->(d)
```